# Excel formula to extract a number and word combination from a string

Tags: excel, string, excel-formula

I'm trying to extra "## seconds" or "## minutes" from cells with strings in them.

| Strings | Desired Output |
| --- | --- |
| Walk 30 seconds fast | 30 seconds |
| Jog 9 minutes slow | 9 minutes |
| Run very fast 1 minute | 1 minute |

I can build a formula to get the number or the measure but I've not been able to create one formula to do both? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

[image]

So you can paste it easily:

```
IFERROR(TRIM(MID(A3,FIND("min",A3,1)-3,10)),TRIM(MID(A3,FIND("sec",A3,1)-3,10)))
```

The iferror tries minutes first then seconds.
Trim gets rid of leading or trailing spaces depending if the number is single or double digit.
Mid() and find() chop out the part wanted. I only used "min" and "sec" in place of "minutes" etc as if there is a typo "minites" for example it would not get found.

Take it apart to see each bit...

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Well, I was going to say here is a "brute force" method, but thanks anyway :) Like your UDF though and I assume "duration" is reserved so you used "durration"?

Comment: I really like your formula.  You are correct `duration()` is a standard Excel function.

Comment: Solar Mike: you nailed it. I modified the formula so I could look up terms (seconds, minutes, hours, and others) from a list of words and it works perfectly! Thank you. Here's a modified formula with LIST being a range of words to look for: =IFERROR(TRIM(MID(A1,FIND(INDEX(LIST,MATCH(1,COUNTIF(A1,"*"&LIST&"*"),0)),A127,1)-3,10)),"")

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following User Defined Function:

```
Option Explicit
Public Function durration(s As String) As String
    Dim t As String, arr, i As Long
    t = LCase(s)
    durration = ""
    
    If InStr(t, "minute") = 0 Then
        If InStr(t, "second") = 0 Then
            Exit Function
        End If
    End If
    
    arr = Split(s, " ")
    For i = LBound(arr) + 1 To UBound(arr)
        t = LCase(arr(i))
        If t = "minute" Or t = "minutes" Or t = "second" Or t = "seconds" Then
            durration = arr(i - 1) & " " & arr(i)
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

[image]

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to **install** and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To **remove** the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To **use** the UDF from Excel:

```
=durration(a1)
```

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Answer (score 0):

-Get the position of the first number in the string:

```
    AGGREGATE(15,6,FIND(ROW($1:$9),A1 & " "),1)
```

-Get the index of space after `minute[s] or second[s]` in the string:

```
    AGGREGATE(15,6,FIND(" ",A1&" ",SEARCH({"second","minute"}, A1&" ")),1)
```

Use the **MID** function, this formula works for me:

```
    =MID(A1 & " ",AGGREGATE(15,6,FIND(ROW($1:$9),A1 & " "),1),
                  AGGREGATE(15,6,FIND(" ",A1&" ",SEARCH({"second","minute"}, A1&" ")),1)- 
                  AGGREGATE(15,6,FIND(ROW($1:$9),A1 & " "),1)
        )
```

[image]

-The reason for using `A1 & " "` is to avoid non-existent spaces after `minute[s] or second[s]`

Comment: Well, functionally similar to mine but seems like a lot more typing...

Comment: Hi @SolarMike, You were right, it looks like I complicated it =)

Comment: That aggregate is so flexible though, have to use it more.